# 'web_link' types in box folder items requests

Tags: box-api

Recently objects with the type 'web_link' started showing up in the items for some of the users that we work with. This currently messes with our application because we expect a 'size' field in all of the entries that Box returns and the 'web_link' type apparently doesn't have a size. I was wondering firstly why this was happening, I think it might be part of some older API that got exposed recent. I am also not sure how to replicate it since the Box API documentation doesn't mention anything about them. Right now our work around will be to just filter the response on our end, but it would be nice to let our users know how they could find and clean up these old objects if they don't need them, so is there a way to specifically search for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our webapp allows users to create "weblinks" that are links to any URL they might come across on the internet.

They only show up in the folder listing API, and they are only used by a small % of users. We may remove them sometime in the near future, which is why they are not included in the documentation.