# Box-Api: Definition of web_link object

Tags: box-api

Although [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028127/web-link-types-in-box-folder-items-requests) mentions that the web_link object only appears in the list API, you can see that the method search for content also returns weblink... and there's no definition of what a weblink is.

Can someone point me in the direction of the definition of this method?

Answer (score 0):

Great question. The weblink object isn't exposed yet. Should be coming soon.